# Question about the simmechanics_to_urdf

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My ROS Version is electric, I hope to show my model drawn by PROE 5.0 in the rviz. I used simmechanics_to_urdf but there is a problem. My xml file is stored in the administrator/ros_workspace, I ran the command rosrun simmechanics_to_urdf convert.py yuanzhu.xml yuanzhu.yaml xml > yuanzhu.urdf. However, the mistake happened:

File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/robot_model/simmechanics_to_urdf/convert.py", line 683, in get
(off,rpy) = self.listener.lookupTransform(parent, child, rospy.Time(0))
tf.ExtrapolationException: Lookup would require extrapolation at time 1356075103.032196045, but only time 1356075103.032871008 is in the buffer, when looking up transform from frame [/____1CG] to frame [/X____1]

I'm new to ROS, if anyone can give me a help, I'll appreciate it. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50919/question-about-the-simmechanics_to_urdf/) by [luxifu1989](https://answers.ros.org/users/3827/luxifu1989/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Copied from [here.](http://answers.ros.org/question/27828/tfextrapolationexception-in-simmechanics_tutorial-package/?answer=51102#post-id-51102)

The first version of the package used a TransformListener/TransformBroadcaster to calculate geometry, when the appropriate behavior is to use a Transformer object. This is what leads to the TransformExtrapolation Error.

The most recent version is available here: https://code.google.com/p/wu-robotics/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fstable%2Furdf_tools.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0